# Template is giving wrong path to media directory and Django can't find the images

Tags: python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have 2 models and their relationship it's OneToMany. So, one "imovel" (portuguese word to property) has many pictures ("fotos" or "imagens" in portuguese).

My web application structure is very simple and I configured at settings:

`settings.py`

```py
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

`urls.py`

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
    path('sobre_nos/', sobre_nos, name='sobre_nos'),
    path('', include('imoveis.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

So every picture that is uploaded, goes directly to 'media' structure and the images for properties goes to `'media/imoveis/%Y/%m/%d'`.

I want to show all pictures associated to a property in a template using a basic bootstrap carousel:

`imovel.html`

```py
  <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      {% for foto in fotos_do_imovel %}
      {% if foto.imagem %}
      <div class="carousel-item activate">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ foto.imagem }}">
      </div>
      {% else %}
       <div class="carousel-item">
         <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ imovel.foto_principal }}">
       </div>
      {% endif %} 
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Proxima</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

The problem is, when I access the page to `imovel.html`, the pictures are not found:

```sh
imoveis/2020/10/01/pexels-photo-1571463.jpeg
imoveis/2020/10/01/pexels-photo-1643383.jpeg
[01/Oct/2020 21:20:35] "GET /imovel/3 HTTP/1.1" 200 5952
Not Found: /imovel/imoveis/2020/10/01/pexels-photo-1643383.jpeg
Not Found: /imovel/imoveis/2020/10/01/pexels-photo-1571463.jpeg
[01/Oct/2020 21:20:35] "GET /imovel/imoveis/2020/10/01/pexels-photo-1571463.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 404 3187
[01/Oct/2020 21:20:35] "GET /imovel/imoveis/2020/10/01/pexels-photo-1643383.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 404 3187
```

I printed the pictures paths inside the view to check if it was alright there, and the view is sending the right path and I don't know where that `imovel/` is added to the front of the correct path and also I don't know how to fix it.

(English is not my first language, so I'm sorry for a few errors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a `FileField` or `ImageField`, you should use the [**`.url`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url) of the file:

```
<img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ foto.imagem.url }}">
```

---

> **Note**: Django does *not* service static and media files in *production*. In production,
> you will need to configure a webserver like *Apache* or *Nginx*. The [Django
> documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-static-files-in-production)
> has sections on configuring the webservers.